# Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() doesn't get correct values of screen resolution

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am having an issue using this method:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
```

I am coding an application in Java using Swing that must be compatible with any screen resolution, because it will be an application for desktop and mobile devices. I've been reading about how to retrieve the screen resolution and everybody refers to this method. I've used it and for my recommendable screen resolution (1920x1080) it works fine, but I realized that, when I change the screen resolution of my monitor (I am working on a laptop) sometimes the ethod does not retrieve the correct screen resolution specified (and yes, I confirm the changes when I change the screen resolution from the Windows configuration).

I've read about the method but I realized that it is not useful for what I am trying to do (I think):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution()
```

My curiosity has led me to check the retrieved values of the method `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` and I've made this table:

[image: Screen configuration - IntelliJ value]

My question here is, how can be this possible? Is this a bug or there is something more to do to retrieve the correct screen size always? I don't understand why I am not getting the correct values always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getScreenResolution() returns the DPI of the screen, it is better to use GraphicsDevice.getDisplayModes();

You can then get the screen height and width from the returned DisplayMode objects.

Also be careful if you have multiple monitors as some methods return the values for the primary display only.

This code  is a bit messy but it might help.

```
for (DisplayMode mode : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayModes())
{
  System.out.println(mode.getWidth() + " x " + mode.getHeight() + "(" + mode.getBitDepth() + ") : refresh rate " + mode.getRefreshRate());
}
```

You can also get the current display mode on the default screen device with

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This method is good but not useful for my case. This retrieves all the display modes available, but I just want to retrieve the current one. there is a way to retrieve the current screen resolutionproperly? or maybe I am doing something wrong when using the getScreenSize() method? Thanks for your help

Comment: GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode() will get you the current mode.

Comment: Got it! You're right. I didn't realized about #getDisplayMode(). Thank you very much. Let me ask you about #getScreenSize().. what could be the reason why this method doesn't work when it suppose it gives you the current screen resolution? I'm talking about #getScreenSize() method

Comment: Without searching the source code for that method, I would have to guess that it may take task bar size into account and also do some calculations based of the DPI of the screen. If I find any better explanation I'll let you know.

Comment: When I set the screen resolution to 1920x1080 the application displays all the components properly, and the value retrieved from the #getScreenSize() method retrieves the correct value, so I guess it is not taking into account anything more than just the current screen resolution. That's why I am not able to understand why in other resolution screens this is not working..

Comment: Yeah, it is very strange, but without some extensive research I'm afraid I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: For me its being crazy too :(... hope someone can bring some more light into this problem I have... Thanks anyway for the information!

Comment: This method is not working, only returning a NullPointerException when replacing `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` with it.